# How to head off a legal reading of a term or phrase?

Tags: connotation, technical, legalese, finance

Terms like 'make whole', 'encumbered', etc have both non-financial/non-legal usages and financial/legal usages and, in some cases, explicit financial/legal definitions.

To avoid technical connotations, to avoid the possibility of a sentence being read as a legal statement, an obvious workaround is to swap in such a synonym.  But synonyms may not exist, or when one does exist, the sentence may unacceptably degrade.

Another remedy is to include a phrase such as 'colloquially speaking'.  But the deprecation could be inappropriate.

What are other ways to minimize the chance of a sentence from being misconstrued in this way?  Is there an adjective or modifer that accomplishes this?

EDITs: adding fictitious examples:

**A divorce can *make whole* both parties.** (google: "make whole" divorce. example: http://www.divorcecentral.com/lifeline/life_ans.html. Make Whole in the sense of closure, in the sense of getting on with their lives)

**The VA is a *monopoly* on veteran healthcare.**  (This sentence was spoken a few minutes ago by Senator Lindsey Graham at his Town Hall, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtzDvmLrK-s at about 40:00.  Monopoly in the sense the VA is immune from competition.)

Comment: I think this is a better fit for our sister site, [Writers.se]. This site doesn't do writing advice; were more focused on the nuts and bolts of English as a language (i.e the way a linguist studies it). We answer questions about syntax, morphology, etymology, orthography, and the like. Stylistic questions are addressed on Writers. Also things like citation formats etc.

Comment: In what context? If you have a specific example, or can craft a model sentence that would employ a word or phrase, this question might be more on topic here.

Comment: added example, and  trying to think of others.

Comment: Those examples are a good start. Now you need to either a) add an intro or follow-up sentence that approximates the "don't take this legally" language that you want (so we know specifically what we're aiming for), or else b) if there is a specific technical term that you want to replace, identify that. Preferably one term request per post of you prefer this approach.

Comment: A possible workaround--use footnotes.  Flag any words or phrases that could have a legal meaning different from what you want to convey, and clarify or explain the intended meaning in the footnote.  That's relatively unobtrusive and doesn't require modifying the body of the document.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem.  The divorce example you give is entirely clear on the web page.  In writing Graham probably would say "The VA has a monopoly" or "The VA is a monopoly in the field of veterans' health care."

Comment: You can use *sensu stricto* and *sensu lato* if need be. from Wiki *lily* - "The term has varied over the years but in modern classification constitutes a broad circumscription (Lilieae sensu lato, s.l.) with eight genera, placed in the subfamily Lilioideae. However older literature frequently uses a narrower circumscription with six genera (Lilieae sensu stricto, s.s.), excluding Tulipa (which now includes Amana) and Erythronium which were treated as a separate tribe, Tulipeae. Within Lilieae s.s., Gagea now includes Lloydia." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilieae

Comment: IMHO, it is best to avoid mixing such terms unless it is _pun_ that you intend. If you need to write a long phrase where you originally intended to use a short one (or a single word), you should do it in the interest of legibility. The confusion is simply not worth it when you don't intend pun. Like: `A divorce can bring closure to both parties.`

Answer (score 0):

*used in a non-technical sense*

Example:

> A divorce can make both parties whole (where I am using "make whole" in a non-technical sense).

You could use the other article if you prefer: "in the non-technical sense."

You can see this phrase being used this way in, for example, *Thinking Arabic Translation: A Course in Translation Method* (which I found by googling): *"the word is being used in a non-technical sense."*